# Populating a Javascript pulldown with a PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

In my web site I have the following:

```
formvalues.php -accesses-> database
database -sends data to be stored in-> formvalues.php

registrationform.php -accesses variables-> formvalues.php
```

### registration form display values accordingly.

I have a piece of javascript code that creates me a basic pull down menu (For testing purposes).

```
var sel = document.createElement('select');
                sel.name = 'staff' + s;

                option1 = document.createElement('option');
                option1.name = 'Non-medical Staff';
                option1.value = 'Non-medical Staff';

                option1.innerHTML = option1.value;

                option2 = document.createElement('option');
                option2.name = 'Nurse';
                option2.value = 'Nurse';
                option2.innerHTML = option2.value;

                sel.appendChild(option1);
                        sel.appendChild(option2);

                document.getElementById('staffarea').appendChild(sel);
```

I was wondering  how do could pass a PHP array variable into the javascript and populate the pulldown instead of manual data.

Do I need to connect it with my formvalues.php file?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to create the dropdown in PHP?

Comment: I have but I need the javascript to add more client side if they are needed by the user.

Thanks

Comment: So if you need more, you can add them via JS, but you can start with the list created on the server. I don't follow why the JS needs access to the PHP data. Perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: //EDIT: Sorry, @Michael Mior: am a slow typer. ;) // Why not print the `select` initially using a PHP loop and then attaching your client side behavior using JS? Printing a JS method call with PHP to create a DOM node is a pretty crazy detour IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing JavaScript from within your php script.
Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = new Array();
<?php
    $your_php_array = array();
    // somehow you populate that array

    foreach ($your_php_array as $key=>$value) {
        echo sprintf("myArray.push(%s);", $value);
    }
?>
    // do stuff with that array in javascript
</script>
```

Of course, if your JavaScript is external, you will have to do a workaround. Such as declaring that JS array as a global variable (still, inside ), and then referencing it with your script.

**$key=>$value** is optional, in case you ever need the key name.